# Defining window buttons in ironpython wpf

Tags: python, wpf, ironpython

I have made a simple GUI where I added manually the close, minimize and maximize buttons.

However, I cant figure out how to add the command that once I click them, they do what expected.

The code looks as following:

```
import wpf
from System.Windows import Application, Window
from teleb_Data import books

class MyWindow(Window):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ui = wpf.LoadComponent(self, 'WpfApplication4.xaml')

    def Name_Search_Click(self, sender, e):
        UserName = self.Name_Text.Text
        print(UserName)
        EXP = books(Name,'lastname')
        print(EXP)

    def Close_Click(self, sender, e):
        pass

    def Maximize_Click(self, sender, e):
        pass

    def Minimize_Click(self, sender, e):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Application().Run(MyWindow())
```

Where instead of pass im not sure what to write.

I tried:

```
def Close_Click(self, sender, e):
    self.ui.Close()
```

But got the error `button is not callable`.

Thank you.

**UPDATE:**

The following Code did the job:

```
def Close_Click(self, sender, e):
    MyWindow.Window.Close()

def Maximize_Click(self, sender, e):
    self.WindowState = self.WindowState.Maximized

def Minimize_Click(self, sender, e):
    self.WindowState = self.WindowState.Minimized
```